# Get first and second td element in row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an ajax call attached to the click event of a pic inside a table row. Once the pic is clicked and the click event initiated, I need to grab the first and second `td` elements from that row. I'm new to jQuery so what I have below is my latest attempt (not working..). The variables `firstName` and `lastName` both wind up being `undefined` after those lines are executed

```
        $('.checkErrors').click(function () {
            var firstName = $(this).parent('tr td:first-child').val();
            var lastName = $(this).parent('tr td:nth-child(2)').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetErrors","AgentTransmission")',
                data: { term: $(this).attr('id') },
                .
                .
            });
          });
```

Here is a sample table row. The image in the last `td` element contains the `.click` event. I would like to grab the first two that contain the text "phinneas" and "ferbseven".

```
<tr>
    <td>
        phinneas
    </td>
    <td>
        ferbseven
    </td>
    <td nowrap>
        7735        
    </td>
    <td>
        Agent
    </td>
    <td>
        SAF
        &nbsp;&nbsp
        07070900  
    </td>
    <td>
        6/5/2013 10:35:38 AM
    </td>
    <td>
        DANTAK
    </td>
    <td class="errorPlus">
        Error
    </td>            
    <td>

        <a href="/AgentTransmission/Details/2358">Details</a>           
            <span> | </span>
        <a href="/AgentTransmission/Edit/2358">Edit</a>        
    </td>
    <td align=center id=2358>
            <img src="/Content/images/magnify.gif" class="checkErrors" id=2358 alt="Program Details" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var $tr = $(this).closest(´tr´);
var firstName = $tr.find('td:first-child').text();
var lastName = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
```

Also, you need to use `text` instead of `val` for `td` elements since it make sense only on input controls.

Answer (score 2):

First only form elements have `.val` property so .

You are supposed to use `.text` since it is a td

Try using `:eq` psuedo selector

```
var $tr;
$tr.find('td:eq(0)').text();

$tr.find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get their content, you can do this:

```
var cells = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td');
var firstName = cells.eq(0).text();
var firstName = cells.eq(1).text();
```

Those last two lines can also be:

```
var firstName = $(cells[0]).text();
var firstName = $(cells[1]).text();
```