# How to update row in the table when data is updated using ajax mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a data table and some data is displayed with in it i have Add Edit and Delete option once the New data is added based up on response i am appending the row to table

```
  GetServerData("Supplier/AddSupplier/", Supplierdetails, function (data) {

    if (data != null) {
       var row = "";
        var Address = data.Address;
        var Area = data.Area;
        var SupplierId = data.SupplierId;
        var SupplierName = data.SupplierName;         
        var Email = data.Email;
    }

    row += "<tr><td>" + SupplierId + "</td><td>" + SupplierName + "</td><td>" + Address + "</td><td>" + Area + "</td><td>" + Email + "</td><td><i class='tbl_edit_btn fa fa-edit Editsupplier' onclick=\"EditSupplier(" + SupplierId + ")\"></i><i class='tbl_del_btn fa fa-trash' data-id=" + SupplierId + "></i></td></tr>"

    $('#suplierlistbody').append(row);
});
```

If i delete row i am removing tr based on the responce i am removeing the row

```
var url = "DeleteSupplier";
$('.DeleteSupplier').click(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $.post(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }, function (response) {
        if (response) {
            row.remove();
        }
    }).fail(function (response) {
        alert("Delete Failed");
    });
});
```

Now I want to edit a row from the table so I have a icon at last column once I click that it will go data base fetches data and binds it to html form

```
function EditSupplier(SupplierId) {

GetServerData("Supplier/GetSupplierById/" + SupplierId, null, function (data) {

    $('#supplier_Id').val(data.SupplierId);
    $('#supplier_name').val(data.SupplierName);
    $('#supplier_address').val(data.Address);
    $('#supplier_area').val(data.Area);       
});
}
```

and i have button below form

```
 <button type="button" id="update">update</button>
```

on update click iam collecting values form text box and passing to controller so that it updates my database if i refresh my page my table is updated but i want to do it with out refresh

```
$(document).on('click', '#updatesupplier', function () {

var SupplierId = $('#supplier_Id').val();
var SupplierName = $('#supplier_name').val();
var Address = $('#supplier_address').val();
var Area = $('#supplier_area').val();

 var Supplierdetails = {
        "SupplierId":SupplierId,
        "SupplierName": SupplierName,
        "Address": Address,
        "Area": Area,
}
     GetServerData("Supplier/UpdateSupplier", Supplierdetails, function(data){
// Here iam getting updated data back now i show modify my table row
});
```

Here is my table

```
    <table class="table " id="suppliertable">
       <thead>
          <td>S.NO</td>
          <th>Supplier name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Area</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
          <th width="100">Action</th>
       </thead>
<tbody id="suplierlistbody">
       @foreach (var items in Model)
       {
       <tr>
          <td>@items.SupplierId</td>
          <td>@items.SupplierName</td>
          <td>@items.Address</td>
          <td>@items.Area</td>
          <td>@items.Email</td>
          <td>
             <i class="tbl_edit_btn fa fa-edit Editsupplier" onclick="EditSupplier(@items.SupplierId)"></i>
             <i class="tbl_del_btn fa fa-trash Deletesupplier" data-id="(@items.SupplierId)"></i>
          </td>
       </tr>
       }
    </table>
```

How Can i update Particular row with latest data...
Thanks

Comment: You could add the supplierId to the <tr id="1"> and then on update replace the origional with the new one. Or you could try knockout.js which will handle this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**, try something like below:

```
GetServerData("Supplier/UpdateSupplier", Supplierdetails, function(data){

    var supplierSelector = "td:contains('"+ data.SupplierId + "')";

    //find and save parent row into variable using .closest() function
    $supplierRow = $(supplierSelector).closest("tr");

    //update name which is the 2nd td element
    $supplierRow.find("td:nth-child(2)").text(data.SupplierName);

    //update Address which is the 3rd td element
    $supplierRow.find("td:nth-child(3)").text(data.Address);

    //update Area which is the 4th td element
    $supplierRow.find("td:nth-child(4)").text(data.Area);

    //update Email which is the 5th td element
    $supplierRow.find("td:nth-child(5)").text(data.Email);

});
```

First [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector is used to find `td` with that has the updated `SupplierId`, after which [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method is used to find the nearest parent `tr` element. For the updates [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to find the correct `td` element and finally [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) updates the supplier with the latest data. Here's another useful link in relation to [table selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989887/get-first-and-second-td-element-in-row).

Note I haven't tested the above code, but I hope the above helps you to get latest data updates on to your `table` elements.

Comment: Thanks @jyrkim It works Made changes in line 2 closing of Double Quotes
var supplierSelector = "td:contains('"+ data.SupplierId +"')";

Comment: @VenkataKrishnaReddy Cheers for the tip, I corrected the code now :-)